# ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor WebGrid tooltip and sorting marker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sorting, razor, tooltip, webgrid

I have developed a webapplication in ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor. I´ve bee using a WebGrid to list tabular data and would like to do xxx things with the webgrid.

**1. I would like for the WebGrid to show which column is the sorting column and if it is sorting ascending or descending.**
I can´t find any property of the WebGrid that seems to handle my wishes. And i cant find anything on the internet...

**2. I would like to add a tooltip to all the column headers (different tooltip for each header)**.
Obviously there are loads of javascript tooltips out there but i haven´t found anything that i can use in the WebGrid...

Answer (score 1):

For q2: 
Give your WebGrid helper an ID

`htmlAttributes:new{id="GridID"}`

Then with Jquery put title for all headers
 
`$('table#GridID th').each(function() { $(this).attr('title', $(this).text()); });`

Comment: Thanks! I solved q2 by using jQuery more or less as you suggested! :-)

Answer (score 0):

For the sorting thingy you can take a look at this post:

[Sort indicator in System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid](http://prokofyev.blogspot.com/2011/01/sort-indicator-in-systemwebhelperswebgr.html)

In the view you can do this:

```
// Force a descending sort only when no user specified sort is present
if (Request.QueryString[grid.SortDirectionFieldName].IsEmpty())
{
    grid.SortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
}
```

and then a custom JavaScript:

```
displaySortIndicators('@grid.SortColumn', '@grid.SortDirection');

displaySortIndicators = function (column, sortDirection) {

    if (column != '') {

        var th = $('thead > tr > th > a[href*="sort=' + column + '"]');

        th.append((sortDirection == 'Ascending') ? "&#9650;" : "&#9660;");
    }
}
```

For the tooltip thingy, you can use [qTip2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/).

NOTE: I use both approaches from links above with the WebGrid helper and they work as expected.

Comment: The 'Sordirection.Ascending'... does not work for some reason. Instead i solved it with a js workaround. Maybe not the cleanest fix, but it works. Not sure why 'Sordirection.Ascending' doesn't work though...